# Como filtrar um array multidimensional dinâmico?

Tags: php

Pessoal sou iniciante no PHP e estou precisando de uma ajuda, como faço para filtrar um array multidimensional dinâmico retirando os arrays que não possuírem um valor especifico?

Pegando por exemplo:
No meu código, faço uma chamada no banco e crio um array dinâmico de acordo com essa estrutura.

```
Array


(  
  [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nome] => Maria
                    [idade] => 22
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [casas_alugadas] => 'S' 
                     [qtd] => 10
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nome] => Joao
                    [idade] => 28
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [casas_alugadas] => 'N'
                )

        )

)
```

Preciso filtrar baseado nos valores, caso o array tenha o elemento "casas_alugadas == N", ele seja excluído e seja passado para o próximo, ficando só o array de índice 0, como feito no exemplo. Como faria isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `array_filter`. Basta passar o *array* que deseja filtrar e uma funções para realização da condição. Nesta função você pode retornar *true* para o *array* ser retornado (um *array* válido) ou *false* para “pular” o *array* e verificar o próximo.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

$arr = [
    [
        [
            "nome"  => "Maria",
            "idade" => 22
        ],
        [
            "casas_alugadas" => "S",
            "qtd" => 10
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "nome" => "João",
            "idade" => 28
        ],
        [
            "casas_alugadas" => "N"
        ]
    ]
];

/* Percorre todos os índices */
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) {

    /**
     * Verifica se o índice `casas_alugadas` existe no
     * índice 1 e se o valor é diferente de "N"
     */
    return $item[1]["casas_alugadas"] != "N";
});

var_dump($arr);
```

<sup>*Demonstração: https://ideone.com/FhXwHO*</sup>

Caso você não saiba o índice, basta usar o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    [
        [
            "nome"  => "Maria",
            "idade" => 22
        ],
        [
            "casas_alugadas" => "S",
            "qtd" => 10
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "nome" => "João",
            "idade" => 28
        ],
        [
            "casas_alugadas" => "N"
        ]
    ]
];


/* Filtra os dados do array */
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) {

    /* Percorre todos os índices */
    foreach($item as $result) {

        /**
         * Verifica se existe o índice `casas_alugadas` e se o valor dele é "S"
         * Caso a condição seja verdadeira, valida e retorna o array
         */
        if (isset($result['casas_alugadas']) && $result['casas_alugadas'] == "S") {
            return true;
        }
    }
});

var_dump($arr);
```

<sup>*Demonstração: https://ideone.com/IyKAkO*</sup>

Comment: Legal, dessa forma eu não sabia, mas ela trata o array e o altera? Preciso retirar esses array, sem mudar a estrutura(Retirar o array e manter o array principal para realizar os sets num foreach)

Comment: @vic.py A estrutura do *array* é mantida.

Comment: @vic.py conseguiu resolver?

Comment: consegui sem problemas muito obrigado pela ajuda!